# Scala generic types and covariance/contravariance

Tags: scala, generics, covariance

I think I've understand the principles of covariance and co. however it seems like i still got problems using it.
Here's an example: I want to write a simple generic immutable Container with a fixed set of values.
So I created a basic Trait

```
trait Container[+A] {

 type B <: A

 def add(elem: B): Container[A]
}
```

Then I started to write concrete classes to represent different containers with different amounts of values, for example an empty container and a container with one element

```
class Container0[+A] extends Container[A] {

  def add(elem: B): Container[A] = new Container1[A](elem)
}  


class Container1[+A](elem0: A) extends Container[A] {

 def add(elem: B): Container[A] = new Container2[A](elem0, elem)
}
```

This compiles fine, however when I try to use it:

```
var t: Container[AnyVal] = new Container0[AnyVal]
t = t.add(5)
```

I get the following error:

```
type mismatch; found : Int(5) required: _3.B where val _3: Container[AnyVal]
```

Comment: try `trait Container[+A] { def add[B >: A](elem: B): Container[B] }`

Comment: The type `_3.B` is a path dependent type. When you say `type B <: A` in your trait definition, you're actually saying that `B` can differ per instance of `Container`. There is no way for the compiler to know that `Int` is compatible with the specific type `B` of the current value of `t`.

Comment: using B >: A didn't solve the problem: now its type mismatch; found : Container[_50.B] where val _50: Container[AnyVal] required: 
  Container[AnyVal]

Comment: You're trying to mutate an immutable container.

Comment: Can you point out where? The return Type of add is a Container so i create a whole new Instance of a Container that is a Copy of the previous container + the element that should be added. I think thats exactly how immutable works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `B` inside `Container` is not visible in the type of a `Container`. So for `add`, all we know is that it requires its argument to be of some type `B` that is possibly more specific than `A`, but we don't know what `B` is. So it's impossible to call `add` (and this is why the error message is so odd).

What are you trying to do with `type B`?

Comment: With type B i wanted to say that it could take any element thats a subtype of A. Hence B <: A. As far as i know I need something like this as I cant just give A as a aarameter since parameters need to be contravariant.

Comment: You actually said "there exists a B such that I can take it", not "for all B :< A, I can take it". To say "for all", you need to put the generic type on each method, like: `def add[B :< A](elem: B): Container[A]`. But actually, that's unnecessary, because you can get what you want with just `def add(elem: A): Container[A]`.

Comment: I guess you haven't tried this since doing:
    def add(elem: A): Container[A] leaves you with the error:
    covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value elem

Comment: @norathem oh, right, I forgot about the covariance. So it should be `def add[B >: A](elem: B): Container[B]`, then. So you get a possibly-more-lax collection out of it.

Comment: thanks that helped. My problem was that I tried to define the type B at the top but this doesn't work. I have to declare it at every methode that uses it.